# Inserted value disappeares after pressing submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a form in HTML that can take the inserted Name by the user and then after pressing submit shows the corresponded value (Age) to that user. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyMain.css">
       <script language="JavaScript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('myshow').innerHTML = 
                        document.getElementById("Name").value;
          }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
            <div>
              <fieldset>
                <form action="">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div form-group">
                      <label for="fname">Your Name: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" placeholder="Jon" value="">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Submit"<br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>

              </fieldset>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>Age: </label>
            <p><span id='myshow'></span></p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that after pressing submit the Name will be shown in the myshow span section(Age:) just 
for a fraction of second and then it disappeares and  url changes to `localhost:5000/?Name=Jack` rather than `localhost:5000/the current path/?Name=Jack`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onSubmit` on the form element to call the function and then return false.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyMain.css">
       <script language="JavaScript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('myshow').innerHTML = 
                        document.getElementById("Name").value;

             return false;
          }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
            <div>
              <fieldset>
                <form action="" onSubmit="return myFunction();">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div form-group">
                      <label for="fname">Your Name: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" placeholder="Jon" value="">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"><br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>

              </fieldset>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>Age: </label>
            <p><span id='myshow'></span></p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

Ps: you did not close the submit tag properly

Comment: Your solution almost is correct but the problem is that, it does not change the URL. Let's say doesn't append the input value to URL. I even changed the form's method to POST but again no change! The final idea is sending the input value to an endpoint and display the result.

Comment: Why do you want to change the url? You can also use `window.location += "?name=X";` to change the url via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need submit. 
If you don't need to submit, You have to change this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyMain.css">
       <script language="JavaScript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('myshow').innerHTML = 
                        document.getElementById("Name").value;
          }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
            <div>
              <fieldset>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div form-group">
                      <label for="fname">Your Name: </label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" placeholder="Jon" value="">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="button" class="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Submit"<br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>Age: </label>
            <p><span id='myshow'></span></p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yesy button works but the problem is URL does not change after submitting! Do you know why? For example I expect ?Name=Jack be added to URL after inserting Jack

Comment: @J2015 read this page. I explain shortly, Form tag is communication element in HTML, If you need to send data to server. you have to use Form tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Your solution has exact effect which submit has, and it does not change the URL too. Let's say doesn't append the input value to URL. I even changed the form's method to POST but again no change! The final idea is sending the input value to an endpoint and display the result.